# Visual Basic & XML file & Combobox --> How to set variables

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox

Good morning,

I am sitting in front of my first Visual Basic project. My intention is to create a small application reading values from an XML file.

My XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Materialien>
<Material name="Aluminium">
<Dichte>2</Dichte>
<EModul>70000</EModul>
</Material>
.......
</Materialien>
```

My VB Code snippet,

```
_dsData.ReadXml("C:\Material.xml")
ComboBox1.DataSource = _dsData.Tables("Material")
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
```

This is working perfectly and I can choose a material from the XML file. So if I choose `Aluminium` in the `combobox` I would like to write `Dichte` and `EModul` into variables. I want to use them inside some calculations or just display them as `Label2` and `Label3`.

Any idea?

Comment: Which window toolkit do you use? WindowsForms or WPF?

Comment: found a solution :) ----- 

        myDataRow = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
        Dichte1 = myDataRow(0)

Comment: In that case I can just say: prima.

Comment: Looks like your XML is a database table. In this case I would recommend using a database instead (even something like SQL LocalDB), and use XML for **configuration**. Use XDocument or XML serialization via class property's properties (no pun intended). If you want a solution, please post as an answer when you can (48 hours after posting your question). Thank you!